# How to search BigQuery query files for specific text?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find a specific query I wrote three months ago that was used to generate a table. I can't remember the name of the file where the query was run.

How can I search through the hundreds of queries to just return the files which match my search terms? The Explorer 'Type to search' function only searches file names.

[image: BigQuery search bar feature]